# AWS S3 how to make folder as today's date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create a folder structure displayed like below.
How should I specify the key?
*Top level folder would be today's date

```
/yyyymmdd/*.jason
```

e.g.
/2021-05-21/example.json

Comment: This depends on your programming language and doesn't have to do with AWS.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to pre-create folders in Amazon S3. Simply upload an object called `2021-05-21/example.json` and the folder will magically 'appear'.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thx for your comment.But I need first make S3 Bucket , and later other system will add *.json file to  proper folder.

Answer (score 0):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. You can create an object with *any* path and the folder magically 'appears'. Then, if the object is deleted, the folder will disappear. Amazon S3 calls them `CommonPrefixes`.

The Amazon S3 management console has a "Create Folder" button. This actually creates a zero-length object with the same name as the folder (e.g. `2021-05-21/`). This 'forces' the folder to appear because there is an object inside it. However, the zero-length object is hidden in the console.

So, if you wish to 'create a folder', simply create a zero-length object with the name of the folder.

Or, better yet, do not create the folder. Just pretend that it exists and things will work perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice. I totally understood!